# Does the WebClient have the same issue as HttpClient that causes socket exhaustion?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I need to download a bunch of different files from a list of URLs, could it cause socket exhaustion in my application? what is the best option to do that? Using WebClient, HttpClientFactory or anything else?

Basically I have a method that downloads the file and I'm calling that from another method, more or less like this:

```
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            await this.Download(url);
        }

        private async Task<byte[]> Download(string url)
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                return await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I faced problems with HttpClient socket exhaustion consuming webservices for the company I work for and I'm wondering if using WebClient today is a correct approach in that scenario or even in a parallelized scenario, using WhenAll for example.

Edit: the comment I replied was deleted

Comment: Do you know how to avoid the socket problem? It's pretty straightforward, then you don't have to switch to WebClient.

Comment: WebClient is slow compared to HttpClient.... The key with HttpClient is to NEVER dispose of it... Never put it inside a "using" statement.... Just use it as a singleton.

Comment: I know how to avoid the socket problem with the HttpClient, I'm using the .net core, so it's pretty easy using HttpClientFactory, I'm wondering if I would have the same problem with WebClient because I could not find much info about that, but after read the MS recommendation I will switcth to HttpClient this piece of code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8